# Is there a way to change the spacing between legend items in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Is there a way to change the spacing between legend items in ggplot2? I currently have

```
legend.position ="top"
```

which automatically produces a horizontal legend. However, the spacing of the items is very close together and I am wondering how to space them farther apart.

Comment: It would be useful to have a current solution to this now that `opts` is depreciated.

Comment: Here: https://pastebin.com/NnxMiTeH

Comment: Tung's answer, currently at the bottom of this thread, has a July 2018 update. Bugs have been fixed and hacky workarounds like the one in the pastebin above are no longer needed.

Answer (score 175):

[`ggplot2 v3.0.0`](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/07/ggplot2-3-0-0/) released in July 2018 has working options to modify `legend.spacing.x`, `legend.spacing.y` and `legend.text`.

Update Dec 2021 - to make `legend.spacing.y` work, you will need to set `byrow = TRUE` in the corresponding guide_legend. [See also this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70526027/7941188). Example below.

**Example: Increase horizontal spacing between legend keys**

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_bar() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_brewer("Cyl", palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  theme(legend.position = 'top', 
        legend.spacing.x = unit(1.0, 'cm'))
```

[image]

Note: If you only want to expand the spacing to the right of the legend text, use [`stringr::str_pad()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50883294/increasing-whitespace-between-legend-items-in-ggplot2/50885122#50885122)

**Example: Increase vertical spacing (mind `byrow = TRUE`)**

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(y = factor(cyl), fill = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_bar() +
  theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(1.0, 'cm'))  +
  ## important additional element
  guides(fill = guide_legend(byrow = TRUE))
```

[image]

**Example: Move the legend key labels to the bottom and increase vertical spacing**

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_bar() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_brewer("Cyl", palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  theme(legend.position = 'top', 
        legend.spacing.x = unit(1.0, 'cm'),
        legend.text = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10))) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Cyl",
                             label.position = "bottom",
                             title.position = "left", title.vjust = 1))
```

[image]

**Example: for `scale_fill_xxx` & `guide_colorbar`**

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = hp), pch = I(21), size = 5)+
  scale_fill_viridis_c(guide = FALSE) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 14) +
  theme(legend.position = 'top', 
        legend.spacing.x = unit(0.5, 'cm'),
        legend.text = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10))) +
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(title = "HP",
                               label.position = "bottom",
                               title.position = "left", title.vjust = 1,
                               # draw border around the legend
                               frame.colour = "black",
                               barwidth = 15,
                               barheight = 1.5))
```

[image]

---

**The below is obsolete, but is left for curious people.**

**For vertical legends**, setting`legend.key.size` only increases the size of the legend keys, not the vertical space between them

```r
ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = cyl, fill = factor(cyl)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_brewer("Cyl", palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"))
```

[image]

In order to increase the distance between legend keys, modification of the `legend-draw.r` function is needed. See this [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2844) for more info

```r
# function to increase vertical spacing between legend keys
# @clauswilke
draw_key_polygon3 <- function(data, params, size) {
  lwd <- min(data$size, min(size) / 4)
  
  grid::rectGrob(
    width = grid::unit(0.6, "npc"),
    height = grid::unit(0.6, "npc"),
    gp = grid::gpar(
      col = data$colour,
      fill = alpha(data$fill, data$alpha),
      lty = data$linetype,
      lwd = lwd * .pt,
      linejoin = "mitre"
    ))
}

### this step is not needed anymore per tjebo's comment below
### see also: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/draw_key.html
# register new key drawing function, 
# the effect is global & persistent throughout the R session
# GeomBar$draw_key = draw_key_polygon3

ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = cyl, fill = factor(cyl)) +
  geom_bar(key_glyph = "polygon3") +
  scale_fill_brewer("Cyl", palette = "Dark2") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(color = NA, fill = NA),
        legend.key.size = unit(1.5, "cm")) +
  theme(legend.title.align = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Your function to increase vertical spacing between legend keys is the only solution I've found that works exactly as I desire and with ease of use. Thanks!

Comment: @tjebo: That's pretty neat. I've updated my answer. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @tjebo which version is that? I'm using ggplot2 3.3.3 and when I try to use it like this ```geom_bar(..., key_glyph = "polygon3")``` I get an ```object 'draw_key_polygon3' of mode 'function' was not found``` error.

Comment: @Anke you still need to define the function as per Tungs answer

Answer (score 85):

I think the best option is to use `guide_legend` within `guides`:

```
p + guides(fill=guide_legend(
                 keywidth=0.1,
                 keyheight=0.1,
                 default.unit="inch")
      )
```

Note the use of `default.unit` , no need to load `grid` package.

Comment: This needs more upvotes, the other answers are outdated.

Comment: This may work for horizontal legends. However, for my vertical legend to the right of the plot, this only increases the key' s height, not the spacing between keys. My legend keys are still very close to each other.

Comment: As Mushin says, this misses the point, as with other answers, if the legend is **VERTICAL** it stretches the legend keys (e.g. the line segments) without padding the space between keys.

Comment: Works nicely together with geom_line and geom_point.

Answer (score 51):

To add spacing between entries in a legend, adjust the margins of the theme element `legend.text`.

To add 30pt of space to the right of each legend label (may be useful for a horizontal legend):

```
p + theme(legend.text = element_text(
    margin = margin(r = 30, unit = "pt")))
```

To add 30pt of space to the left of each legend label (may be useful for a vertical legend):

```
p + theme(legend.text = element_text(
    margin = margin(l = 30, unit = "pt")))
```

for a `ggplot2` object `p`. The keywords are `legend.text` and `margin`.

[Note about edit: When this answer was first posted, there was a bug. The bug has now been fixed]

Comment: The bug has now been fixed, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: See also Tung's answer for a July 2018 update on these matters.

Comment: If you want to add space between items in a vertical legend on the bottom and top of each entry, try something like `margin = margin(t = 5, b = 5, unit = "pt")`.

Answer (score 49):

A simple fix that I use to add space in horizontal legends, simply add spaces in the labels (see extract below):

```
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","blue","white"),
                    labels=c("Label of category 1          ",
                             "Label of category 2          ",
                             "Label of category 3"))
```

Comment: This is the only answer so far which deals with the question! This might be helpful in case of many entries: `scale_fill_manual(values=values, labels=setNames(paste(labels, "    "), entries))`.

Comment: Technically not very nice, especially when you have to introduce those spaces into factor levels, but it's the only working solution so for.

Comment: Or we can use [str_pad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50885122/786542) to make life a little bit easier

Answer (score 39):

Now that `opts` is deprecated in `ggplot2` package, function `theme` should be used instead:

```
library(grid) # for unit()
... + theme(legend.key.height=unit(3,"line"))
... + theme(legend.key.width=unit(3,"line"))
```

Comment: This solution changes the height/width of the boxes as opposed to the spacing between them.

Comment: I needed to decrease the spacing between vertical legend items. Setting `legend.spacing.y` to a negative value didn't work but `legend.key.size=unit(.8,"lines")` did.

Answer (score 31):

Looks like the best approach (in 2018) is to use `legend.key.size` under the `theme` object. (e.g., see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32277045/4581200)).

```
#Set-up:
    library(ggplot2)
    library(gridExtra)

    gp <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl, colour = factor(cyl))) +
        geom_point()
```

This is **real easy if you are using `theme_bw()`:**

```
  gpbw <- gp + theme_bw()

#Change spacing size:

  g1bw <- gpbw + theme(legend.key.size = unit(0, 'lines'))
  g2bw <- gpbw + theme(legend.key.size = unit(1.5, 'lines'))
  g3bw <- gpbw + theme(legend.key.size = unit(3, 'lines'))

  grid.arrange(g1bw,g2bw,g3bw,nrow=3)
```

[image]

However, this **doesn't work quite so well otherwise** (e.g., if you need the grey background on your legend symbol):

```
  g1 <- gp + theme(legend.key.size = unit(0, 'lines'))
  g2 <- gp + theme(legend.key.size = unit(1.5, 'lines'))
  g3 <- gp + theme(legend.key.size = unit(3, 'lines'))

  grid.arrange(g1,g2,g3,nrow=3)

#Notice that the legend symbol squares get bigger (that's what legend.key.size does). 

#Let's [indirectly] "control" that, too:
  gp2 <- g3
  g4 <- gp2 + theme(legend.key = element_rect(size = 1))
  g5 <- gp2 + theme(legend.key = element_rect(size = 3))
  g6 <- gp2 + theme(legend.key = element_rect(size = 10))

  grid.arrange(g4,g5,g6,nrow=3)   #see picture below, left
```

Notice that white squares begin blocking legend title (and eventually the graph itself if we kept increasing the value).

```
  #This shows you why:
    gt <- gp2 + theme(legend.key = element_rect(size = 10,color = 'yellow' ))
```

[image]

I haven't quite found a work-around for fixing the above problem...
Let me know in the comments if you have an idea, and I'll update accordingly!

- I wonder if there is some way to re-layer things using `$layers`...

Comment: Make the `legend.key` transparent: `theme(legend.key = element_rect(size = 30,color=alpha("transparent",0)))`

Comment: this was the most straightforward answer and easiest to use imo

Answer (score 17):

From Koshke's work on ggplot2 and his blog ([Koshke's blog](http://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/adjust-key-width-and-key-height-of-legend-in-ggplot2/))

```
... + theme(legend.key.height=unit(3,"line")) # Change 3 to X
... + theme(legend.key.width=unit(3,"line")) # Change 3 to X
```

Type `theme_get()` in the console to see other editable legend attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and link to Koshke's blog! Unfortunately however this seems to change the size of the boxes but not the spacing between items.

Comment: You may be able to "fake" it with some type of overlaying grob. But I don't think theres a way to get extra spacing inside of the legend. This is the only mention of it I could find in ggplot2's mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ggplot2/PhkJpP8zJuM

Comment: I can use this to increase spacing between legends successfully. Using negative numbers helped decrease spacing between legends.

Answer (score 6):

Use any of these

```
legend.spacing = unit(1,"cm")
legend.spacing.x = unit(1,"cm")
legend.spacing.y = unit(1,"cm")
```

Comment: My issue with this is that the labels for the legends end up occupying the middle portion of the extra white space, as opposed to generating space between the colored boxes of the legend. I've found the answer offered here about padding under `theme(legend.text)` to be the most satisfying for this.

Answer (score 0):

As of ggplot2 3.5.0, legend spacing has been reworked.

To manipulate spacing between different legends, use the `legend.spacing` setting.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class, shape = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(ncol = 2))

p + theme(
  legend.spacing = unit(1, "cm")
)
```

[image]

To control spacing of key-label pairs within legends, uses the `legend.key.spacing` settings. For historical reasons the y-spacing does not inherit from the main `legend.key.spacing` setting, so you'd have to explicitly state `legend.key.spacing.y` in that case.

```r
p + theme(
  legend.key.spacing.x = unit(1, "cm"),
  legend.key.spacing.y = unit(1, "cm")
)
```

[image]

To manipulate the spacing between the labels and the keys, use the text margins.

```r
p + theme(
  legend.text = element_text(margin = margin(l = 1, unit = "cm"))
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-27 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>