# ggplot2 increase space between legend keys

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I increase the space between the keys of the legend of `ggplot2` plot?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl)),
       , data = mtcars) +
      geom_point() +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", 
        legend.position = "bottom") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(nrow=2))
```

[image]

I am looking for a ggplot2 option that add a kind of vertical adjustment between (key 4 and key 6) in the plot above? Should I create a custom legend key?

PS: I want to increase the blank space between boxes not between labels.

the desired plot is :

[image]

NOTE: **No the question is not duplicated of the other question. We want here to add a vertical spacing between items that are already in multiple rows. In the other question we have 1-row legend and we want to add spaces (horizontal) between items.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366964/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-spacing-between-legend-items-in-ggplot2). Did that solve your issue?

Comment: @Heroka no.it is not a duplicate.I don't want to change the key size. just the space between the keys. You can try the solution in the link to check this.

Comment: `grid` or `gridExtra` might help, I've never used them much though... [The `gridExtra` vignette](https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/arrange-ggplot#Legends) looks somewhat promising, but is far from giving a clear solution.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

An alternative (and probably easier) solution is using `legend.key` and `legend.key.size` in the `theme` part of your code:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 2)) +
  theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
        legend.position = 'bottom',
        legend.key = element_rect(size = 5),
        legend.key.size = unit(1.5, 'lines'))
```

this gives:

[image]

---

In case you are calling `theme_bw` or `theme_classic` before manipulating the legend, you should set the color of the legend rectangle:

```
legend.key = element_rect(size = 5, color = 'white') #or: color = NA
```

Comment: Could you explain the difference between the size property of `legend.key` and the  `lines` property of `legend.key.size`. Which one controls the spacing between the keys (i.e., the grey boxes + the label)?

Comment: @BerkU. The `size` parameter of `legend.key` determines the size of the boundary line. The `lines` property of `legend.key.size` determines the size of the whole box.

Comment: This did not solve my situation, because the ``lines`` made some legend symbols increase together with the box. In my situation, the point symbol did not increase (same as your example) but the line symbol did. As my lines were vertical, the box kept getting taller as ``lines`` was increased, without increasing the space between the two columns of the legend. Will report back if I find a solution.

Comment: @PatrickT Not sure what your problem is. Maybe post as a new question?

Comment: @Jaap, The problem came to bite me again and I couldn't remember if I had resolved it last time around (see my comment on 30 Sep 2017), so I posted a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668265/ggplot2-increase-space-between-legend-keys-without-increasing-legend-keys

Comment: @Jaap: [Note that this solution doesn't work for vertical legend w/ `ggplot2 > v3.0.0`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3180)

Comment: @Tung Thx for notifying. Do I understand that issue right that there is no way of doing this anymore? Will try to look into it later.

Comment: @Jaap: Unfortunately not. You'll have to [modify `ggplot` code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50615868/786542) if you want to change the vertical spacing

Answer (score 8):

Here a solution  using `gtable`. Basically I am extracting legend grobs table and I add a row in the legend table.

```
library(gtable)
library(grid)
## transform the ggplot to a grobs table
p_table <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
## extract legend
leg <- which(sapply(p_table$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
## this is the tricky part !
## add  a row in the second position (pos=2)
p_table$grobs[[leg]]$grobs[[1]] <- 
  gtable_add_rows(p_table$grobs[[leg]]$grobs[[1]], 
                  unit(0.5, "line"), ## you can increase the height here
                  pos=2)             ## since I have 2 rows , I insert it in the middle
plot(p_table)
```

*PS: I dont' know here how to coerce the table  to a plot again! maybe someone else can help here ( I am just plotting it and losing the object structure)*

[image]