Well-spaced color bar labels with short numerical ranges in ggplot2 heat maps
I'm trying to plot a ggplot2 heat map filling it with values that range from 0 to 0.7. I wanted the legend color bar labels to have well-defined spacing, i.e. 0 at the bottom, 0.05 in the middle, and > 0.1 at the top. However, the labels are overlapping at the bottom.
How can I space them out?
My code for editing the plot's legend:
theme (plot.title       = element_text (family = "OS", face = "bold", size = 16, color = "black", hjust = 0.05),
       plot.subtitle    = element_text (family = "TNR", face = "plain", size = 14, color = "black", hjust = 0.05),
       axis.text        = element_text (family = "OS", size = 12, color = "black"),
       legend.position  = c(0.9, 0.1),
       legend.title     = element_text (family = "TNR", size = 14, color = "black"),
       legend.text      = element_text (family = "TNR", size = 14, color = "black"), 
       legend.spacing.y = unit (100, "cm"),
       panel.background = element_rect (fill = "white"))                                    +

guides               (fill = guide_colorbar (direction = "horizontal", 
                                             title.position = "top",
                                             label.position = "top")) +

scale_fill_gradientn (limits = c(0, 1), 
                      breaks = c(0, 0.05, 1),
                      labels = c("0", "0.05", "> 0.1"),
                      colors = rev (palette [c(1, 3, 5)]), 
                      na.value = "white")


Please include enough data and code for a working plot. You are currently asking us to make up data and a plot to even have a chance to see the overlapping labels you are asking about.

I have added an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50527096/set-custom-non-linear-scale-bar-with-ggplot2
