# Add vertical spacing to ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting

I'm having trouble adding vertical spacing to the y axis on a pie chart, without also stretching the color boxes, is there a way to keep the color boxes the same size (square), while increasing the vertical spacing between each element?

I've tried a bunch of different things from modifying `theme(legend.text = element_text(margin = margin(t = 1,b = 1, unit ='cm')))` to `legend.spacing.y`, and `keyheight`, but nothing seems to work so far.

**Example:**

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(Color = c("Blue", "Red", "Green"), pcts = c(.45, .25, .30))
df1$ymax <- cumsum(df1$pcts)
df1$ymin <- lag(df1$ymax, 1, default = 0)

df1 %>% ggplot(aes(ymax = ymax, ymin = ymin, xmax = 4, xmin = 2.85, fill = Color)) + 
  geom_rect() +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(margin = margin(t = 1, b = 1, unit = 'cm')))
```

Also, the below charts are rendered using `Cario`, but the default graphics device produces the same result.

[image: Example #1]

**Desired legend:**

[image]

Comment: Using the same code I have your desired legend. Maybe the problem is related to some graphics option and not to the code...

Comment: @Terru_theTerror are you on a Mac?

Comment: Hmm... just tried on a Mac and I get the same result in my question, any idea  what the graphics setting could be?

Comment: I'm on windows.

Comment: Marking as a duplicate because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668265/increase-space-between-legend-keys-without-increasing-legend-keys) solves the problem, note that for a custom color palette, you need to add `aesthetics = c("fill", "color")` to your `scale_color/fill` call