# Spacing between legend keys in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a legend on the top of the graph. I want the legend to be left aligned and to be able to set the spacing (1) between the aesthetic symbol (colored square) and the text and (2) between the text and the next aesthetic symbol.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(transmission = ifelse(am, "manual", "automatic")) %>% 
ggplot() +
  aes(x = transmission, fill = transmission) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(fill = NULL) +
  theme(
    #legend.spacing.x = unit(.5, "char"), # adds spacing to the left too
    legend.position = "top", 
    legend.justification = c(0,0),
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    legend.margin=margin(c(5,5,5,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2 increase space between legend keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275113/ggplot2-increase-space-between-legend-keys)

Comment: s. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366964/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-spacing-between-legend-items-in-ggplot2/26971729

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding a margin to [adjust](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1502) `element_text`

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(transmission = ifelse(am, "manual", "automatic")) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = transmission, fill = transmission) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(fill = NULL) +
  theme(
    #legend.spacing.x = unit(.5, "char"), # adds spacing to the left too
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.justification = c(0, 0),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.margin = margin(c(5, 5, 5, 0)),
    legend.text = element_text(margin = margin(r = 10, unit = "pt")))
```

[image]

Comment: is counter-productive for my case (vertical legend): adding margin to the text shifts text in relationship to the keys...

Comment: Use `l` instead of `r` for vertical legends:
```
legend.text = element_text(margin = margin(l = -5, unit = "pt")
```