# Barplot customization

Tags: r

So I have this data table

```
   AA  BB  CC  DD
W1 3.5 3.5 3.4 3.5
w2 3.4 3.7 3.6 3.5
w3 3.5 3.4 3.5 3.5
w4 3.5 3.4 3.5 3.5
w5 3.5 3.4 3.5 3.5
w6 3.5 3.4 3.5 3.5
w7 3.5 3.4 3.5 3.5
w8 3.5 3.4 3.5 3.5
```

and code

```
qw<-barplot(as.matrix(t(tabela.matrix1)), beside=TRUE, 
           col=c("yellow", "cornflowerblue", "yellowgreen","orchid4"))
text(qw, 0, round(as.matrix(t(tabela.matrix1)), 1),cex=1,pos=3,srt=90) 


#legend("bottom",
     # c("AA","BB","CC", "DD"),
      # fill=terrain.colors(4)
)
```

that outputs this barplot
[image]

**Now I would like to plot this barplots, place the legend outside barplot and also rotate leters w1, w2, w3, w4... for 45 degrees.**:

[image]

Picture above was created in excel.

Comment: For your legend see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932038/plot-a-legend-outside-of-the-plotting-area-in-base-graphics ie 
You can also use `xpd` for the labels. Try `mat <- as.matrix(t(tabela.matrix1)) ;qw <- barplot(mat, beside=TRUE,  axisnames = FALSE,  col=c("yellow", "cornflowerblue", "yellowgreen","orchid4")) ; text(colMeans(qw[2:3,]), -0.25, labels = colnames(mat), xpd=TRUE, srt=45); legend(1,-0.5,  c("AA","BB","CC", "DD"), fill=terrain.colors(4), horiz=TRUE, xpd=TRUE)`

Comment: @user20650, thanks. That was helpful.

Comment: You're welcome... please feel free to expand upon it and add it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the facetting works as well, it is also possible to make the bars smaller. Off course with adjusting the dodging of bars and text:

```
ggplot(xym, aes(x = Var1, y = value, fill = Var2)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0.2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.7, position = position_dodge(width=0.7)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = Var1, y = 0.05, label = round(value, 2), fill = Var2), 
            angle = 90, position = position_dodge(width = 0.7), size = 4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This one comes close. I'm not happy with the dodging.

```
xy <- matrix(runif(4*8), nrow = 8, ncol = 4)
colnames(xy) <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD")
rownames(xy) <- paste("w", 1:nrow(xy), sep = "")

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
xym <- melt(xy)

ggplot(xym, aes(x = Var1, y = value, fill = Var2)) +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
    theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0.2)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    geom_text(aes(x = Var1, y = 0.05, label = round(value, 2), fill = Var2), 
              angle = 90, position = position_dodge(width = 1.03), size = 4)
```

[image]

---

This is a trivial extension of @Roman's solution, putting the `W`s into facets.

```
ggplot(xym, aes(x = Var2, y = value, fill = Var2)) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0.2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(x = Var2, y = 0.1, label = round(value, 2), fill = Var2), 
            angle = 90, position = position_dodge(width = 1.03), size = 4)+
  facet_grid(.~Var1, scales="free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: @ Roman Luštnik, how can I add  morespace between group of bars. In other words, add space like  in my picture above (excel version)?

Comment: I added the faceting approach to your answer. Please feel free to remove.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful addition, @jlhoward.

Comment: I've added an example with improved dodging, you were not happy about Hope it makes you happier ;-).

Comment: As it was rejected as an edit, i will have to post it below as an answer.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik 3 people did, because "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer". So i posted it as an answer, although it felt a bit like stealing your code. Although the improvement is gigantic off course... ;-)

Comment: Is it possible to add more space between labels in legend? I tried **"p + guides(fill=guide_legend(
                 keywidth=0.1,
                 keyheight=0.1,
                 default.unit="inch")
      )**  but it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Miha see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366964/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-spacing-between-legend-items-in-ggplot2