# Is there a function that plots a barplot having years on the x-axis and values on the y-axis?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have this data:

```
Year    A    B      C       D       E
Y2000   6.8  5.3    36.7    41      10.2
Y2001   2   10.6    40.3    37.8    9.3
Y2002   2.2  8.8    38      40.6    10.5
Y2003   2.3 14.2    41.6    33.8    8.1
Y2004   2.9  6.8    42.3    38.3    9.7
Y2005   5.5 11.9    39.1    43.4    NA
Y2006   6.4  8.6    32.4    41.1    11.4
Y2007   7.7 13.7    29.6    38.9    10
Y2008   9   10.4    36.5    38.8    5.2
Y2009   NA    NA    50.9    49.1    NA
```

and code

```
attach(Data)
mydata <- factor(format(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), length.out=10, by='1 year'),'%Y'),
                 levels = format(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), length.out=10, by='1 year'),'%Y'),
                 ordered = T)

colnames(Data) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
xym <- melt(mydata)

ggplot(xym, aes(x = Data$Year, y = value)) +
      theme_bw() +
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
      theme(legend.position = "right", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0.2)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
      geom_bar(fill = c("green", "blue", "red", "yellow", "black")))
```

I am struggling to get the plot that I want. It should be similar to the plots in this question:
[Barplot customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678197/barplot-customization)

Comment: Hi, please comply [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Comment: what's the purpose of `xym`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get a similar barplot to the one you linked.
I left all the settings you set up in your example.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

Data <- tibble::tribble(
    ~Year,    ~A,    ~B,      ~C,       ~D,       ~E,
    "Y2000",   6.8,  5.3,    36.7,    41,      10.2,
    "Y2001",   2,   10.6,    40.3,    37.8,    9.3,
    "Y2002",   2.2,  8.8,    38,      40.6,    10.5,
    "Y2003",   2.3, 14.2,    41.6,    33.8,    8.1,
    "Y2004",   2.9,  6.8,    42.3,    38.3,    9.7,
    "Y2005",   5.5, 11.9,    39.1,    43.4,    NA,
    "Y2006",   6.4,  8.6,    32.4,    41.1,    11.4,
    "Y2007",   7.7, 13.7,    29.6,    38.9,    10,
    "Y2008",   9,   10.4,    36.5,    38.8,    5.2,
    "Y2009",   NA,    NA,    50.9,    49.1,    NA
)


Data %>%
    pivot_longer(-Year) %>% 
    
    ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = name)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") + 
    theme(legend.position = "right", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0.2))
```

[image]
I don't know if you want to copy the labels too.