# The titles of multiple legends do not align with position="bottom" in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider this plot:

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2) 
df.m <- data.frame(Var1=c("A","B"), Var2=c("B", "A"), Similarity=c(97.5,92.5),
                       Rank=c("In", "Out"))

p <- ggplot(df.m, aes(Var1, Var2, fill=Similarity, col=Rank)) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = muted("red"),
                       mid = "white", high = muted("blue")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "gold"))
```

[image]

The titles of the legends do not align. When i add guides, this happens:

```
p +   guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill="white")),
         fill=guide_legend(title.hjust=0.5))
```

The titles now align, but the continous-nature of the fill-legend is lost.
[image]

What can i do?

Comment: where does `muted` come from?

Comment: sorry, its scales

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50615868/786542

Answer (score 5):

You can add `legend.box.just = "center"`

```
ggplot(df.m, aes(Var1, Var2, fill = Similarity, colour = Rank)) +
  geom_tile() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.box.just = "center")
```

[image]

Comment: That is already nice. Is there a way to also align the key boxes?

Comment: @nouse can't help with that, sorry.