# Cannot set margins in ggplot2 legend.text

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, margins

I am trying to increase the margins between texts in a legend. 
My understanding is that this should be controlled with margins in theme - legend.text - element_text. This doesn't seem to work. Actually, any type of setting, including jhust, vjust, seems not to work with legend.text.
Can anyone help?

In the example below I have put some absurd values for margins, with no results (see picture attached).

```
library(tidyverse)
data(midwest, package="ggplot2")
plot <- ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill=state), stat="identity") +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=2)) + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette ="Set1" ,labels = str_wrap(c("AAA AAA","BBB    BBB","C","DDD DDD","E"),5)) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.text=element_text(margin=margin(t=100,r=100))
```

[image]

This is the real case on which I am trying to work.

[image]

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/50615868/786542

Comment: The code just resizes the legend.keys; but little space remains between legend texts.

Comment: You need to scroll further down