# How to reduce the legend symbol thickness for a bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Was asked to reduce the legend symbol thickness for a bar chart in ggplot2 (need them so thin that they look like narrow horizontal lines). Here is a simplification of my case:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Simple bar chart example
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = drv))
g
```

[image]

```r
# Failed attempt to reduce the thickness of the legend symbol using guides(). 
# I also tried negative values, but that gives errors. 
# However, increasing the size works well. I need the symbols very thin.
g2 <- g + guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 0.1)))
g2
```

[image]

```r
# Also adjusting with some theme options is not really working for me
# nor what I really need because is also reducing the distance between the labels.
g + theme(legend.key.height = unit(0.1, "mm"))
```

[image]

Perhaps there is no other way around than editing the legend grobs themselves with the functionality of the `grid` package or do this outside of R, like Inkscape (?).

<sup>Created on 2019-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: By "thickness" you mean narrow lines? Vertical or horizontal?

Comment: Hi @PoGibas, yes, narrow lines, horizontal. I'll edit the text to be more clear then.

Comment: @Valentin: scroll to the end of this answer to see if it's what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/50615868/786542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to change legend shape. This solution is not perfect (too complicated) as you have to add `geom_point` layer for which you can change shape.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, fill = drv)) +
  # Remove legend for bar
  geom_bar(show.legend = FALSE) +
  # Add points to a plot, but invisible as size is 0
  # Shape 95 is a thin horizontal line
  geom_point(aes(y = 0, color = drv), size = 0, shape = 95) +
  # Reset size for points from 0 to X
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10)))
```

[image]

---

Another solution is to add `geom_line` layer (ie, line is a thin bar):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, fill = drv)) +
  geom_bar(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_line(aes(y = NA, color = drv), size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: I like your creativity @PoGibas. I doesn't fully solve my particular issue because I also have `geom_line` in use and some tiny point symbols appear now in the legend of line symbols (as I said my graph is much more complex). Also `aes` `color` and `fill` are both taken already by other `geoms`. I'll up-vote and consider for accepting since it solves the depicted simplified problem, but I'll wait a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I made use of the [creative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56235174/5193830) of @PoGibas to add a `geom_line` and then edit manually the `guides`. Since the `color` aesthetic was used by another geom, I had to use other available aesthetics, and `linetype` was a good candidate. I accepted @PoGibas 's answer, but hopefully the code below adds to the diversity of the solution:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.5.3
library(scales)  # just for getting the default colors

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = class)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = drv),
           show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_line(aes(y = 0, # y must be provided, so force it to 0 (if forced to NA, it appears in the OY axis)
                linetype = drv)) + # can be any unused aesthetic 
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = "solid",
                                                     color = scales::hue_pal()(3),
                                                     size = 1)))
```

[image]

So, can apply the same principle if we 'force' use `alpha` aesthetic as well and then edit the `guides` as needed.

```r
  ggplot(mpg, aes(x = class)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = drv),
             show.legend = FALSE)+
    geom_line(aes(y = 0,
                  alpha = drv)) +
    guides(alpha = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1, # 1 is recycled 3 times here, as size is below as well
                                                    color = scales::hue_pal()(3),
                                                    size = 2)))
#> Warning: Using alpha for a discrete variable is not advised.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I guess that for line `y = 0` and `size = 0`, because now on y-axis you have `NA`. And then reset line sine with `guides`.

Comment: Thanks @PoGibas for noticing, I set `y = 0` and the `NA` vanished from the OY axis