# R ggplot 2 legend border issue

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting, legend

I know this is minor, but it's for a publication and will drive me crazy. The bottom of the P0688 box is like 1-2 pixels thinner than the rest. I don't want to make the borders thicker because then it doesn't match the rest of the bar chart.

```
  plot<- ggplot(tukey_letters, aes(x = variable, y = value.x, 
        fill = L1)) + 
      theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="#ffffff", color 
      ="#000000"), panel.grid.major=element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge(),color="black")+ scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FFFFFF", "#999999"))+ guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Genotype", title.position = "left")) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value.x-se, ymax=value.x+se), width=.1,size=.5,position=position_dodge(0.9), color="black")+
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(size =12, face="bold"),
    axis.text = element_text(angle=30, vjust=0.5,hjust=0.6,size=8,face="bold", color="#000000"),
    axis.ticks = element_line(size = rel(1)),
    axis.ticks.length = unit(0.3, "cm"),
    legend.position = c(0.2, 0.9)
  )+
  labs(
    x="Treatment",
    y="ARI1"
  )+
  #facet_wrap(~L1)+ ## You can use face_wrap function only if you need it+
  geom_text(data =tukey_letters,
            aes(x=xpos, y=ymax+offset_asterisk,label=groups), 
           size = 4,position=position_dodge(0.9) , vjust=-0.5
 )
```

[image: Bottom of P0688 box]

[image: It's not even that noticeable at a smaller size. Still bothers me.]

Thanks in advance. Let me know if there is anything else needed to help solve this.

Comment: [You may want to check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366964/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-spacing-between-legend-items-in-ggplot2).  Look for u/Tung's answer (currently the one at the top).  Looks like for vertically-positioned fill legends (like you have), there is still kind of an issue with small spacing differences (it bugs me too - totally get it).  Refer to to [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2844) for some additional info.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. Maybe I was implementing something incorrectly because legend.spacing.y was not changing the distance between the white and grey boxes.

Comment: Yeah - I fiddled with it a good 10 min before I found the post and the specific case where vertical legends with fill are kinda bugged.  :/  Can you switch to horizontal? :)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the filling behaviour of the legend keys. It's a known issue, see this GitHub thread https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2844. There is also a fix suggested on this site, let me show this here.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(fill=factor(cyl), x=cyl) +
  geom_bar(color = 'black') +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title.position = "left")) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(color="white") +
        legend.position = c(0.2, 0.7))
```

[image]

Enlarged, the legend will look now like this: 
[image]

**Now let's do the fix.**

```r
  draw_key_polygon3 <- function(data, params, size) {
  lwd <- min(data$size, min(size) / 4)

  grid::rectGrob(
    width = grid::unit(0.7, "npc"),
    height = grid::unit(0.7, "npc"),
    gp = grid::gpar(
      col = data$colour,
      fill = alpha(data$fill, data$alpha),
      lty = data$linetype,
      lwd = lwd * .pt,
      linejoin = "mitre"
    ))
}

GeomBar$draw_key = draw_key_polygon3

ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(fill=factor(cyl), x=cyl) +
  geom_bar(color = 'black') +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title.position = "left")) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(color="white", fill = 'white'),
        legend.position = c(0.2, 0.7))
```

[image]

**But what is actually going on here**? Let's see!

```r
ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(fill=factor(cyl), x=cyl) +
  geom_bar(color = 'black') +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title.position = "left")) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.2, 0.7),
        legend.key = element_rect(color="black", fill = 'white'))
```

The legend has two borders! One for the legend glyph, the other for the key. You draw the border for the key with the call to `theme`, and the border around the glyph is created with your color argument in `geom_bar`

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>