# R: Increase vertical spacing between legend items using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a line chart using ggplot. I want to increase the vertical spacing between my legend items (text **and** symbols)

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366964/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-spacing-between-legend-items-in-ggplot2) about this problem. However, isn't there a more simple (i.e. without writing a function) solution to this problem?

I tried the command `legend.spacing.y` but that only moves the entire legend up and down and not the spacing between the items.

Also, I tried:
`theme(legend.text = element_text(margin = margin(t = 1, unit = "cm"))))`
However, this **only** moves the text and **not** the items.

Could anybody please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this in a pipe with `tidyverse`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    mutate(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(mpg, wt, colour = cyl)) +
   geom_point() +
  theme(
        legend.key.size = unit(1.5, 'lines'),
        legend.key = element_rect(size = 5, color = 'white'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
        legend.key.size = unit(1.5, 'lines'),
        legend.key = element_rect(size = 5, color = 'white'))
```

Output:

[image]