# Spacing of Legend Items in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to know how to increase the space between legend items in ggplot. This comes in handy when you have more involved plots and the viewer needs a clear legend of a color gradient, which is sometimes hard to see when you don't have enough whitespace between the parts of a color gradient.

**REPREX**

```
data(iris)

iris$Sepal.Length.cut<-cut(iris$Sepal.Length, breaks=seq(4,8,1), labels=c("here","and here","here too", "here three"))

iris.grad<-colorRampPalette(c("darkgoldenrod","darkgoldenrod4"))
iris.col<-iris.grad(4)
names(iris.col)<-levels(iris$Sepal.Length.cut)

ggplot(iris)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=Species,fill=Sepal.Length.cut), stat="count")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=iris.col, name="increase space \n where indicated")+
  theme(legend.spacing.y=unit(1.5,"lines"))
```

legend.spacing.y only increases the space between the title and the legend elements, increasing the key size doesn't get rid of the problem. Interestingly enought [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366964/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-spacing-between-legend-items-in-ggplot2) actually says it should and their reprex works for me... maybe its the difference between bars and points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by specifying `guide_legend(byrow = TRUE)` before adding the spacing to your theme.

```r
ggplot(iris) +
  geom_bar(aes(Species, fill = Sepal.Length.cut), stat = "count") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=iris.col, name = "increase space \n where indicated") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(byrow = TRUE)) +
  theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(1.5, "lines"))
```

[image]

Comment: ahhhh, yes, in my original (not reprex) I had also specified the guide via scale_fill_manual and that created a conflict. I didn't even think to reproduce that somehow!